# how to move change the cat output into columns

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, cat

so this is my out put when i cat multiple config files and grep name of file and modified date.

```
/path-to-file/name of file
modified date
/path-to-file/name of file
modified date
/path-to-file/name of file
modified date
```

I want the output to be like this and if possible add comma after the word 'file'.

```
/path-to-file/name of file, modified date
/path-to-file/name of file, modified date
/path-to-file/name of file, modified date
/path-to-file/name of file, modified date
```

Comment: By writing shell script, read two line and write a single line.

Answer (score 1):

pipe your output to `awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,NR%2?", ":"\n"}'`

Comment: thanks perfect...how would i do it without the commas? cause i get two commas...one on top and bottom.  log.7’,

Comment: @fer remove the comma in awk one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe your output into `paste -d, - -` which will join each pair of lines from the input.